# how to set text in run method in surface view?

Tags: android, textview, surfaceview

I have SurfaceView and Run() method , Its like a loop , how can i edit textView text in this Run method ?
I wrote :

```
  textView1.setText("my text");
```

It didn't work ? any Ideas ? 
the code summary is :

```
public class GFXSurface extends Activity {

MySurface ourSurfaceView;
TextView textView1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
            }

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

       @Override
       public void run() {
           //here i want to edit textView1
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you show a bit more code as to where the Run() method is

Comment: I will just a minute @kabuto178

Comment: You'll probably have to do that code on the main thread. I'm assuming your Run() function runs on another thread.

Comment: Ahh that does make it clearer, as Shaquil said I think its not changing because your trying to change UI from another thread.

Comment: would you take a look please @kabuto178

Comment: so how can i change that ? @kabuto178

Comment: Is there a way to perform that ? @ShaquilHansford

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter Views that were initialized on the main thread from another thread. You should look into using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post on the UI thread. It wouldn't be wise to update a TextView inside that run method either, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting text to your `TextView` using the `runOnUiThread()` method call, for example the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
   //here set the textview content
  }
});
```

Comment: It needs @something before it what should I write ?

Comment: `@Override` before the `run()`